# Angular - How to drag/drop with Dragula service based on a condition

Tags: angular

Is there any way to drag only if a variable inside the typescript is true, also after drag can I call a function to save this sorting directly to DB?
so far I solved auto saving after drop but I can't use two services with dragula (one to handle and the other to call for a sorting function )

I can't use both two services in the same time

```
this.dragulaService.createGroup('chapters-list', {
  moves: function (el, container, handle) {
    //the only way I found here is just to check if a class name exists in the html
  }
});

this.dragulaService.out('chapters-list').subscribe((value) => {
  this.updateSorting();//This works fine after drop it will update to db
});
```

Comment: call the dragula createGroup service from the instructor and keep the drop service in onInit here you will be able to use both services but for to check variable if true or false inside createGroup I don't think it would work

Comment: Thank you this works for calling two services now the issue about if variable condition is true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way can works is to set boolean variable in TS and in view check if this variable is true then add/remove class

```
 <div [ngClass]="canDrag?'':'edit-mode'">
```

and in Dragula createGroup add this condition

```
 return !handle.classList.contains('edit-mode');
```